# Adding Text before certain values in a query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am building a wedding database for a class and currently have a table for Expenses. The table displays the expense label (flowers, photographer, band....) and due date for payment (among other things). I also have a separate table for other tasks (ask bridal party, send invitations....).

I currently have a Union Query that combines the two tables into one "To-Do List". Here is the sql for the query:

```
SELECT Expense AS Task, DateDue, tblExpenses.[Paid?] AS [Completed?]
from tblExpenses
UNION SELECT Task, DateDue, tblToDoList.[Completed?]
from tblToDoList;
```

My problem is the final list combined as planned, but the list has values such as "flowers" under the "Task" heading. I want to be able to add "Pay for" or "Paid" in front of the values that came from the expenses table so that it reads like a predicate instead of a subject. Is there a way to do this?

Sorry if any of this is confusing. My knowledge of SQL is very limited and I am not sure how to phrase everything exactly.

Comment: Is there a column you can JOIN the two tables on? It seems from your explanation that tblExpenses and tblToDoList contain two different kinds of things, but then you have things in the ToDo List that can be paid or not. So I'm a bit confused. But if the two tables have a column in common, think about using JOIN instead of UNION

Comment: If you mean by some key, then no they don't currently. I am a true beginner at building a database and relationships within the database has always been a weak spot for me. Basically, tblexpenses is a subset of tasks from tblToDoList that has additional information attached to it. (I think this is a correct way of looking at it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about .. ?

```
SELECT Expense AS Task, DateDue, 
       IIf(tblExpenses.[Paid?]=True,"Paid","Pay For") AS [Completed?]
FROM tblExpenses
UNION 
SELECT Task, DateDue, tblToDoList.[Completed?]
FROM tblToDoList;
```

If paid is true (yes) the query will return "Paid", otherwise it will return "Pay for".

Re comment

```
SELECT "Paid " & Expense AS Task, DateDue, 
       tblExpenses.[Paid?] AS [Completed?]
FROM tblExpenses
UNION 
SELECT Task, DateDue, tblToDoList.[Completed?]
FROM tblToDoList;
```

Comment: I don't think I clearly stated my goal. The [Completed?] field is working fine.

Currently, values that are returned from tblExpenses in the "Task" field just say Flowers, Photographer etc. I want them to return as Paid Flowers, Paid Photographer etc.

Comment: Always paid? If so, you can just fill in the word as text as illustrated above.

Comment: Wow. I tried every iteration of this last night, but was making it too complicated. This should work, but Melanie's comment above made me think that their might be a better way to build my tables from the start. Thanks a ton either way!

Comment: You might like to dive into http://r937.com/relational.html, because @Melanie has a very good point indeed. You expenses table should be related to your task list in some way.